# d2: importing function from external library under different name it was originally exported

Tags: linker, static-linking, d

I am translating 3rd party library API written in C to D. That library exports a lot of functions named like `libname_foofunc`, `libname_barfunc` etc., which is expectable for C library to prevent bloating global namespace. As D is more modular than C, I want to provide more D'ish interface and get rid of function prefix, so functions will look like `libname.c.foofunc` and `libname.c.barfunc`.

As library is unaware of my "improvements", I have to somehow translate `libname.c.foofunc` into `libname_foofunc` and preserve correct extern-linkage, destination name mangling and calling convention at the same time.

Assuming there is way (which I don't know either) to tell linker that external unresolved symbol `__imp__D1c7foofuncFZi` corresponds to `_libname_foofunc` or `libname_foofunc@0` (despite the fact I have to do name mangling by hands), there is still problem telling D what calling convention is.

In case I explicitly specify `extern(C) int foofunc()` in `libname/c.di`, there is no longer calling convention problem, but name gets translated to `_foofunc`, which also differs from expected.

**So, is there way in D to import foreign function under different name than it was exported?**

I've though about importing functions "as is" under their original names and then alias-ing them to prefixless analogues, but this seems to be quite clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as linking goes, symbols are really a C thing, since we're talking about the C linker. D's situation with linking and exported symbols is basically the same as it is in C++, which is why there are mangled names and the like. You're going to have to create declarations for them in D using their original names, because that's what the linker is going to expect. D doesn't do anything different or magical which would change that. There are only two ways that you're going to be able to use different names.

1. alias the functions in your D code. You can just put the aliases in whatever module lists the symbols (since you have to declare them in D anyway). Then your code could use either the original names or the aliases. I don't see anything clumsy about that.
2. Create wrapper functions - either in C or D - and have your D code use those.

The aliases would definitely be better IMHO. They don't introduce any overhead and are less complicated.

But regardless, the normal thing to do when using C libraries from D is just to use the C function names. You're calling C functions, and that fact shouldn't be hidden. They're not D functions and don't act the same (even if they're similar) - especially when it comes to stuff like who owns the memory of what you're passing to functions. The gain in renaming them is debatable. It's usually when a D wrapper is written to give an API a cleaner, more D-like API (and not just changing the names) that the C functions aren't used directly anymore. A good example of this in Phobos would be etc.c.curl vs std.net.curl. etc.c.curl is purely the C API and doesn't attempt to rename anything. It doesn't create any aliases to make the symbols match Phobos' naming conventions or make them more D-like. It's essentially just the D version of the curl's header files. std.net.curl, on the other hand, builds on top of it to provide a more D-like API and abstraction. It does far more than rename the C functions.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
alias libname_foofunc foofunc;
```

this will keep the `libname_foofunc` visible but allows you to use `foofunc` and it will be transformed by the compiler into `libname_foofunc`

Comment: I've mentioned this kind of temporary workaround in last paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the last paragraph of the OT, the answer is NO. No other language can do it either, the way you described, and it should not.  If API designers wanted to have function names in the way you like, they would expose them that way...

Now imagine group A of developers who prefer `some_function()`, then group B who prefer `someFunction()`, and group C who prefer `SomeFunction()`...

Aliasing is a must, no matter whether you use D or something else. And it should be that way. API should be simple, and concise, and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to put the functions into modules you can keep them inside structs and simulate some sort of namespaces. E.g. you can do this:

```
struct libname
{
    struct C
    {
        static int libname_foofunc();
        alias libname_foofunc foofunc;
    }

    static C c;
}

void main()
{
    libname.c.foofunc();
}
```

Comment: Oh, this trick seems neat - I can declare it just as static struct, so there will be no need in `static C c`... Very nice, thank you!

Comment: Yeah I didn't think of making the definition static. I don't know when that started working. Also __gshared should probably be static there, __gshared doesn't do anything on function declarations like that.